# (most likely due to a circular import) how to switch between multiple pages in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

i've been trying to create a little app for navigate between three pages using tkinter, all the pages are written in different python files, the scripts are bellow.
First file for start page:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import first_window as fw
import second_window as sw
class Library_Management_System(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        #create a frame who's contain the frames
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


        self.frames = {}     #create a dictionaries for frames
        for f in (StartPage, fw.first, sw.second):
            frame = f(container, self)
            self.frames[f] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.show_frame(StartPage)
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        tk.Frame.configure(self, bg='red')
        first_button = ttk.Button(self, text='Page One',
                            command = lambda : controller.show_frame(fw.PageOne)).pack()
        second_button = ttk.Button(self, text='Page two',
                            command = lambda : controller.show_frame(sw.second_window)).pack()


app = Library_Management_System()
app.geometry('200x200+200+200')
app.mainloop()
```

Second file for first page:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import main as m
import second_window as sw
class first(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        tk.Frame.configure(self,bg='red')
        second_button = ttk.Button(self, text='Page Two',
                            command=lambda : controller.show_frame(sw.second_window)).pack()
        start_button = ttk.Button(self, text='Start Page',
                            command=lambda : controller.show_frame(m.StartPage)).pack()
```

Third file for second page:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import main as m
import first_window as fw
class second(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        tk.Frame.configure(self, bg='green')
        start_button = ttk.Button(self, text='Start Page',
                            command=lambda : controller.show_frame(m.StartPage)).pack()
        first_button = ttk.Button(self, text='Page One',
                            command=lambda : controller.show_frame(fw.first_window)).pack()
```

i get this error:

```
    for f in (StartPage, fw.first, sw.second):
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'first_window' has no attribute 'first' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

why it doesn't recognize the module first.

Comment: Are you sure it is not supposed to be `fw.first_window` ?

Comment: fw is the shortcut of first_window.
The name of the class is 'first'

Comment: Ironically after reading this post, I had the exact same circular error on a completely separate problem.  It turned out to be a problem with how I was separating the code in their own files and importing them.  I'd check to make sure each file has the correct imports, and isn't importing themself.